# Sample pairs to satisfy a condition

Tags: r, duplicates, conditional-statements, sample

I have this problem I cannot figure out. I have 500 samples of Group A from Uniform distribution. And there are 500 samples of Group B from another Uniform distribution.

I will select one value, a from A, and another value,b from B. 
I want to make 'a is always smaller than b'. I would like to get 500 pairs without duplication.

```
A <- runif(500, min = 19, max= 23)
B <- runif(500, min = 22, max= 26)
```

How can I get 500 pairs of (a,b) which are a < b, without duplication?

---

### Edited:

Sorry, I need to make clear my question.
Once Group A and B is set, it will not be changed. 500 of pairs should be selected from fixed A and B. In the each pair, a < b.

I want to see 'random' effect like Monte Carlo. so, I think just sorting cannot help this problem.

Comment: So to be clear, A and B are fixed, and you want a permutation of B such that `all(A<B)`? This may not be possible.  If A is `c(22.5, 22.7)` and B is `c(22.1, 22.2)` there is no permutation of B that satisfied the request.

Comment: A and B are fixed, and you want a permutation of B such that all(A<B)? YES

Comment: If A is c(22.5, 22.7) and B is c(22.1, 22.2) there is no permutation of B that satisfied the request.....**BUT, in this case, we have 500 of A and B, I thick it is possible to find 500 combinations that satisfy A<B **

Comment: please have a look at my answer..i am curious whether i attempted the question correctly or not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the prettiest solution, too. Anyway, I solved it!
I used sample function with a condition and replaced a selected value with NA to prevent the duplication.

```
A <- runif(500, min = 19, max= 23)
B <- runif(500, min = 22, max= 26)

B.largerthan.A <- function(A,B) {
  result = c()
  i <- 1
  while (i < 500) {
    Select.B <- sample(B[!is.na(B)], size=1)
    if ( (Select.B < max(A,na.rm=TRUE)) & (!is.na(Select.B)) ) {
      Select.A <- sample((A)[(A<Select.B) & (!is.na(A))], size=1)
    }  else {
      Select.A <- sample((A[!is.na(A)]),size=1)
    }

    result = rbind(result, c(Select.A, Select.B))
    A[which(A == Select.A)] = NA
    B[which(B == Select.B)] = NA
    i=1+i
    if (length(B[!is.na(B)]) == 1) {
      Select.B <- B[!is.na(B)]
      Select.A <- A[!is.na(A)]
      result = rbind(result, c(Select.A, Select.B))
      A[which(A == Select.A)] = NA
      B[which(B == Select.B)] = NA
      break
    }}
  return(result)
}

A_B <- B.largerthan.A(A,B)
```

It yields:

```
> any(A_B[,1] < A_B[,2])
[1] TRUE
```

If you have any tidier idea. Please let me know.
THANK YOU!!

Comment: I fixed my answer, it was pretty trivial bug!

Answer (score 3):

Since the range of A and B is different, we can sort the sets and check whether the sorted vectors yield pairs that fulfill the desired condition.

```
C <- sort(A)
D <- sort(B)
```

Now we need to check whether the pairs `C[i]`, `D[i]` fulfill the condition `C[i] < D[i]` for all `i`:

```
> !!sum(C > D)
#[1] FALSE
```

In this case we are lucky: all pairs satisfy the necessary condition. If this test had returned `TRUE`, we could have tried generating new sets of random numbers.

Now we have pairs `C[i]`, `D[i]` with entries selected from `A` and `B`, respectively, such that `C[i] < D[i]` for all 500 values of `i`.

Duplication is practically impossible in floating-point numbers.

Comment: This yields a very non-uniform distribution -- this essentially samples from a very small distance off the line from (19, 23)-(23,26)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The sets A and B are generated in the same way; using the same distribution as described in the OP. The goal is to find pairs where one is smaller than the other. This is achieved here.

Comment: I see; you read the problem very differently than I did, but I can see your point; the question is to "select one value, ... and another value".  My interpretation (probably incorrect) is that OP wanted to sample 500 pairs from that range subject to that condition.

Comment: Thanks, @RHertel. Your method definitely work. However, it will give similar difference value between C[i] and D[i]. I want to see more 'random' effect like Monte Carlo. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Preserving my previous answer below based on my original interpretation of the question.

I don't think the question as posed represents the real problem you're trying to solve.  I would suggest posting more information on the underlying problem to give more motivation.

To summarise the problem statement as is, you want to pair `A` with a permutation of `B` that satisfies the condition that `A<B`.  In addition, you want the resulting set of pairs to be uniformly distributed over the resulting set, which looks like this:

[image]

The problem is that the x values here are uniformly distributed over `[19,23]`, which means that all bands of x values will have the same number of points, and since the right-hand side bands have smaller volume (because of the excluded triangle) the density will be higher on that side.  So it is impossible to achieve a uniform sampling via any permutation of `B`.

If you are planning to use this distribution for Monte Carlo evaluation of something inside this object, your result will be incorrect because you'll be oversampling in parts of the set, and thus undersampling in others.

The only way to correct for this is to either resample, as below, or just discard all pairs that fall into that corner, and use less than 500 points to do the computation.

---

This is only partially a software question, I think.

First off, what do you mean by "duplication"? `runif` is extremely unlikely to produce duplicates in the sense of numerically identical values.

Assuming that we can ignore that condition, this is a question of rejection sampling; namely, you want to sample from a rectangle, with a clipped corner.  Specifically, this is a 5x5 square (area 25) minus a 1x1 triangle (area 1/2).  The simplest way to go about this is to sample a larger amount, and then take the first 500 that satisfy the condition.

If we start with a data frame of size 1000

```
df <- data.frame(A=runif(1000, min=19, max=23), B=runif(1000, min=22, max=26))
```

We can filter down and get the first 500:

```
df2 <- head(df[df$A < df$B, ], 500)
rownames(df2) <- NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, @user295691. I think I need additional explanation, I do not want to get duplicate pairs. If I got a pair of (a,b), a should be removed from Group A and it should not be selected for next sample. and my intent was that the distribution should not be changed after re-sample. I think I need to pick the pairs from fixed group.

Comment: This is a pretty sharp observation! You are right! The permutated pairs will be only in the area excluding the triangle. I will consider your comment. Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

If it is imperative to draw from the original A and B, I propose this:

```
A <- runif(500, min = 19, max= 23)
B <- runif(500, min = 22, max= 26)
used <- rep(F, 500)

library("foreach")

newB <- foreach(a=A, .combine=c) %do% {
  ind <- which(B>a & !used) # pool of available B values
  if (length(ind)==0) # ie no remaining element of B is over a!
    stop("This is quite unlikely but let's catch it just in case")

  b <- B[ind] # pool of available B values

  i <- sample(length(b), 1) # draw an index at random from b
  ### code was faulty here
  used[ind[i]] <- T # flag it as used, it won't be drawn again
  ### 
  return(b[i]) # return the value
}


foreach(b=B, a=A, .export="B", .final=function(x) {print("Everything is ok")}) %do% {
  if(sum(newB %in% b)>1) 
    stop("There are duplicates")
}

foreach(b=newB, a=A, .export="B", .final=function(x) {print("Everything is ok")}) %do% {
  if(a>b)
    stop("There are invalid pairs")
}
```

Which yields:

> [1] "Everything is ok"

There are neither duplicates or invalid pairs.

EDIT: I fixed it. Obviously the test that everything was ok was broken too, it is also fixed.

Comment: Thank you! This is a great idea! But, when I plot density graphs of B and newB, I found they show different distributions. Do you have any idea to show same distribution? Thanks!

Comment: It is litterally impossible since B and newB are the exact same samples (in a different order). Their histogram (hence distribution) are the same. You must be doing something wrong ;) 

How are you plotting the distributions?

Comment: Actually you are right. So my code does not do what I expect it to do. It is a programming issue, but the underlying method is valid and will yield the same distribution.

Comment: I fixed it. The problem was the indexing of `used` (No sense at all to index it by `i`, should have been `ind[i]`!)

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest solution, but it works. Careful to choose feasible min and max values for A and B though.

```
A <- runif(500, min = 19, max= 23)
B <- runif(500, min = 22, max= 26)

while(any(A>B)) {
  i <- which(A>B)
  A[i] <- runif(length(i), min = 19, max= 23)
}
```

There you go.

```
> any(A>B)
[1] FALSE
```

Duplication is not an issue as you are drawing from a continuous distribution.

> The expected number of iteration of the loop is left as an exercise
>   for the reader.

EDIT: well I got curious so here is what the average number of iteration looks like, plotted against the number of row of the data.

[image: Average number of iteration versus size of the data]

As you can see, it is in `O(log(size))`.

Code:

```
library(foreach)
x <- 10^seq(2,5,.5)

res <- foreach(size=x, .combine=data.frame) %:%
  times(1000) %do% {
    A <- runif(size, min = 19, max= 23)
    B <- runif(size, min = 22, max= 26)
    counter <- 1
    while(any(A>B)) {
      i <- which(A>B)
      A[i] <- runif(length(i), min = 19, max= 23)
      counter <- counter +1
    }  
    counter
  }

plot(x, colMeans(res), log = "x", 
     xlab ="Size of the data (log scale)", ylab="Expected #iteration")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @antoine-sac. My intent was that the distribution should not be changed after re-sample. I think I need to pick the pairs from fixed group.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works.

**Data**

```
A <- runif(500, min = 19, max= 23)
B <- runif(500, min = 22, max= 26)
```

**Chain Sapply And Lapply**

```
result<-sapply(B,function(b){b>lapply(A,function(a){a})})
```

**Extracting Indices**

```
indices<-which(result,arr.ind = TRUE)
```

**Using Indices To Subset A and B Vector and Put all Pairs in Data Frame**

```
df<-as.data.frame(x=cbind(A=A[indices[,1]],B=B[indices[,2]]))
```

**To take 500 samples from this**

```
library(dplyr)    
df_sampled<-sample_n(df,500)
```

**Some Tests**

```
all(df$A %in% A)
[1] TRUE
all(df$B %in% B)
[1] TRUE
all(df$A < df$B)
[1] TRUE
```

This gives data frame of much larger pairs than 500. We can easily take 500 samples from this :)

**Some Samples From the Resulting Data Frame**

```
sample_n(df,10)

              A        B
79298  19.95930 25.24061
8990   22.47500 25.00853
151784 19.50021 25.81786
189713 20.82555 25.68779
27653  21.47545 23.62572
180116 22.36681 22.50472
52052  21.00113 24.63401
171574 20.11955 22.89538
88720  19.22706 23.98680
25766  21.88181 24.56297
```

Comment: Sorry for the late check. Your method is technically right. However, My intent was that the distribution of A and B are not changed even after the permutation. My and antoine-sac's code can solve this problem, but I need to consider user295691's comment to see a Monte Carlo. Thank you guys!!